# Holder estimate for eigenfunctions of Laplace operator on sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to ask if there is a holder esitimate for eigenfunctions of Laplace operator on sphere? I mean the esimate for
\begin{equation}
\|\partial^{\alpha}h_n\|_{L^{\infty}(S^{d-1})}
\end{equation}
in term of $n$, where $h_n$ is the $n^{th}$  eigenfunction (in the orthonormal basic of $L^2(S^{d-1})$ composed of eigenfunctions).\
If $\alpha=0$, I've found the following result
\begin{equation}
\|h_n\|_{L^{\infty}(S^{d-1})}\le C_1\lambda_n^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\le C_2 n^{\frac{d-1}{2d}}.
\end{equation}
Thanks in advance for your help!